# Google App Engine: who is an admin?

Tags: google-app-engine, admin

In your `app.yaml` configuration file you can required `login: admin`. My question is now "what" or "who" is an admin?

In the App Engine console in the `Administration -> Permissions` section they're also talking about an `admin`. However, if you add a new user you can only choose between `owner`, `developer` and `viewer`.

Which of those is an `admin`? Only the `owner` or `owner`+`developer` or all three?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When working with users either on your own apps domain or normal Google users:

- Owners can do anything supported by the UI.
- Only Owners can make changes on the Permissions tab (invite, change role, remove).
- Developers can do anything except changes on the Permissions tab.
- Viewers cannot change anything.
- Everyone who was an admin before feature went live is initially an Owner. (This is available since version 1.4.2)

All three roles are given admin status when the application runs (i.e., users.is_current_user_admin() returns True).

Comment: "If you run GAE on your own domain: Everyone in the control panel ("Manage this domain") with the flag "Administrator Privileges" will have administrator rights in your application." This is INCORRECT. Only admins added in the App Engine app's admin console will be an administrator.