# Who is treated as administrator of GAE application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, python-2.7

In accordance with [GAE quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail), I can send up to 5000 mails to administrator of the app. But who is treated as administrator? The according Permissions page in the Administration section of GAE console has three users defined:

- `admin@mydomain.com` with role `Developer`
- `me@gmail.com` with role `Owner`
- `somebodyelse@gmail.com` with role `Viewer`

Who is app administrator? First two, all of them or just the second one?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090727/google-app-engine-who-is-an-admin), but it doesn't cover email sending part.

Comment: In case it's not clear, the separate quota only applies when you use the special methods (send_mail_to_admins for python). Sending an email to one of the admin addresses using the regular send_mail function will consume the normal quota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admin emails get sent to all users who are defined in the project permissions, there is no way to be selective.

To send the emails use the **AdminEmailMessage** class from **google.appengine.api.mail**, if you use **EmailMessage**, then they will come off of your 100 free Recipients Emailed quota, rather than the 3,492,979 Admins Emailed quota.

Example:

Include this import at the top of your script:

```
from google.appengine.api.mail import AdminEmailMessage
```

Then use this syntax to send the admin emails.

```
AdminEmailMessage(
    sender = "your@adminaccount.com",
    subject = "Hello Admin",
    body = "A test admin email"
).send()
```

This will send an email to all users defined in the projects permissions.

They will then come off of your **Admins Emailed** quota, rather than your **Recipients Emailed** quota, as they would if you used the **EmailMessage** class.

[image]

You can use any of [these fields](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields), apart from **to**, **cc** & **bcc**.

Comment: Does it mean that if I send the message with `send_mail` to `me@gmail.com` (and not with `send_mail_to_admins`), then it is counted against regular `Messages Sent` quota and not `Admins Emailed`?

Comment: What if I want to send a message to the user and CC admin? I'll have to use `send_mail` in this case. Will it be counted as 2 messages within `Messages Sent` quota?

Comment: What runtime are you using? Php, Python, Java or Go?

Comment: I've updated the question with the tags. I use Python 2.7. Another question - what happens with I send the message like `EmailMessage.send()`? Does it call `send_mail`?

Comment: I have updated my answer above, you need to use AdminEmailMessage, not EmailMessage.

Comment: Thanks. Where have you taken that 3,492,979? The google doc says about 5'000 message. And, what is about my 2nd comment? Will I have to send 2 messages then (`EmailMessage` and `AdminEmailMessage`)?

Comment: 3,492,979 is from the Quota Details section within the App Engine console https://appengine.google.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51103/discussion-between-iangsy-and-la)